# DialogFlow ES - how to get chatbot to perform a "monologue" type message

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, digital-persona-sdk

I'm new to Google's DialogFlow and am using it with Soul Machines to create a digital person. I've been learning it through brute force methods. I want this person to present some content, basically just walking through some information in a monologue style rather than a normal chatbot dialog. It would be as if I was standing in front of a camera talking and explaining some concept that I'd eventually put on a website. How do I do this?

I can't quite seem to figure out how to add a bunch of intents that would be triggered by the previous one like how a human would be triggered by new cue cards. I don't want to shove all my content in one intent and make it a long stream of consciousness, but that's all I've got figured out right now. Is there a way to make a custom payload to trigger them? The documentation from both DialogFlow and Soul Machines aren't quite helpful with this.

Appreciate any advice and tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow agents don't start conversations - normally, they are triggered by any start event (a WELCOME type of event, one message asking for something, etc).

I've seen some customers creating API mechanisms where some backend API sends an initial message to the bot and the bot response acts as the first message to the human user. But yet, to move forward on the conversation, the agent will still need user interactions (ie. answering simple yes/no questions, etc).